# How to color an semiplane delimited by one axis?

Tags: tikz-pgf, color

In my code below I made an complex plane with the real axis and imaginary axis

CODE:

```
 \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage[brazilian]{babel}
  \usepackage{tikz}
  \begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
         \draw [thin, gray, ->] (0,-2) -- (0,2)      % draw y-axis line
         node [above, black] {$j\omega$};              % add label for y-axis
         \draw [thin, gray, ->] (-2,0) -- (2,0)      % draw x-axis line
         node [right, black] {$\sigma$};              % add label for x-axis
         \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{document}
```

FIGURE:

[image: complex_plane]

But now I want to color the left semiplane (delimited by the jw axis) of this complex plane.

The color should be transparent because the axis in the left semiplane still needs to be showing

How can I do this?

Comment: `\fill [blue] (0,-2) rectangle (-2,2);` ? Probably I don't understand the question. (Certainly, I don't understand the question, in fact.)

Comment: @cfr it is like this, but the blue color should be transparent in order to the axis in the left semiplane continues to be showing in the figure. I should apologize because I did not make a well written question, because my english it's not very good.

Comment: You can draw the axes *after* the `\fill` command. Or use `\fill [blue,opacity=.3] ...;` to make the filling transparent (play with the `opacity` value to get your most desired result).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub>Answer composed from the comments, therefore community wiki.</sub>

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill [yellow] (-2, -2) rectangle (0, 2); % fill left semisphere
    \draw [thin, gray, ->] (0,-2) -- (0,2)    % draw y-axis line
      node [above, black] {$j\omega$};        % add label for y-axis
    \draw [thin, gray, ->] (-2,0) -- (2,0)    % draw x-axis line
      node [right, black] {$\sigma$};         % add label for x-axis
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]